# Vanilla Javascript accessing a private method variables from within a different constructor function

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to build a drawing app for my University task and I am forced to use encapsulation for this and object oriented programming. Using P5.js, I have 2 constructor functions, first constructor (as you can see below) has a few methods out of which has one private method that "gets" the color that the user clicks. The second constructor is just a tool to draw circles.

By default, the first constructor has a fill option. From within the second constructor I am drawing circles and I've made a button that once clicked, removes the fill or adds it back.

My problem is here, once I click to remove the fill, it works, but when I want to apply the fill back to any future circle drawing, I can't access the first constructor's private method to get the current color that the user picked.

I have tried, within my main sketch.js file, to create a new colourPalette (first constructor function) assinging it to a variable and then when creating the main CircleTool (second constructor function) I passed as an argument this variable thinking that I will be able to access the colourPalette from within the second constructor, see the below code:

Main sketch.js file:

```
var toolbox = null;
var colourP = null;
var helpers = null;

function setup() {

    //create a canvas to fill the content div from index.html
    canvasContainer = select('#content');
    var c = createCanvas(canvasContainer.size().width, canvasContainer.size().height);
    c.parent("content");

    //create helper functions and the colour palette
    helpers = new HelperFunctions();
    colourP = new ColourPalette();

    //create a toolbox for storing the tools
    toolbox = new Toolbox();

    //add the tools to the toolbox.
    toolbox.addTool(new FreehandTool());
    toolbox.addTool(new LineToTool());
    toolbox.addTool(new SprayCanTool());
    toolbox.addTool(new mirrorDrawTool());
    toolbox.addTool(new CircleTool(colourP));
    background(255);

}

function draw() {
    //call the draw function from the selected tool.
    //hasOwnProperty is a javascript function that tests
    //if an object contains a particular method or property
    //if there isn't a draw method the app will alert the user
    if (toolbox.selectedTool.hasOwnProperty("draw")) {
        toolbox.selectedTool.draw();
    } else {
        alert("it doesn't look like your tool has a draw method!");
    }
}
```

colourPalette constructor:

```
function ColourPalette() {
    //a list of web colour strings
    this.colours = ["black", "silver", "gray", "white", "maroon", "red", "purple",
        "orange", "pink", "fuchsia", "green", "lime", "olive", "yellow", "navy",
        "blue", "teal", "aqua"
    ];
    //make the start colour be black
    this.selectedColour = "black";
    
    var self = this;

    var colourClick = function() {
        //remove the old border
        var current = select("#" + self.selectedColour + "Swatch");
        current.style("border", "0");

        //get the new colour from the id of the clicked element
        c = this.id().split("Swatch")[0];

        //set the selected colour and fill and stroke
        self.selectedColour = c;
        fill(c);
        stroke(c);

        //add a new border to the selected colour
        this.style("border", "2px solid blue");
        return c;
    }

    //load in the colours
    this.loadColours = function() {
        //set the fill and stroke properties to be black at the start of the programme
        //running
        fill(this.colours[0]);
        stroke(this.colours[0]);

        //for each colour create a new div in the html for the colourSwatches
        for (var i = 0; i < this.colours.length; i++) {
            var colourID = this.colours[i] + "Swatch";

            //using p5.dom add the swatch to the palette and set its background colour
            //to be the colour value.
            var colourSwatch = createDiv()
            colourSwatch.class('colourSwatches');
            colourSwatch.id(colourID);

            select(".colourPalette").child(colourSwatch);
            select("#" + colourID).style("background-color", this.colours[i]);
            colourSwatch.mouseClicked(colourClick)
        }

        select(".colourSwatches").style("border", "2px solid blue");
    };
    //call the loadColours function now it is declared
    this.loadColours();
    this.selectedColor = function() {
        var color = colourClick();
        fill(color);
    }
}
```

CircleTool Constructor:

```
function CircleTool(palette) {
    this.name = "circleTool";
    this.icon = "/assets/circle.jpg";
    this.colorPalette = palette;

    var startMouseX = -1;
    var startMouseY = -1;
    var drawing = false;
    this.draw = function() {
        //Function to draw the circle
        if(mouseIsPressed) {
            if(startMouseX == -1) {
                drawing = true;
                startMouseX = mouseX;
                startMouseY = mouseY;
                loadPixels();
            }    
            else {
                updatePixels();
                ellipse(startMouseX,startMouseY,dist(startMouseX,startMouseY,mouseX,mouseY));
            }        
        }
        else if(drawing) {
            drawing = false;
            startMouseX = -1;
            startMouseY = -1;
        }
    }
    //adds a button and click handler to the options area. When clicked
    //toggle the fill of the circle
    this.populateOptions = function() {
        select(".options").html(
            "<button id='directionButton'>Fill circle</button>");
        //  //click handler
        select("#directionButton").mouseClicked(function() {
            var button = select("#" + this.elt.id);
            if (self.axis == "fill") {
                self.axis = "notFill";
                console.log(colorPalette);
                button.html('Circle not Filled');
            } else {
                self.axis = "fill";
                self.lineOfSymmetry = width / 2;
                noFill();
                button.html('Circle Filled');
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Now, inside the CircleTool constructor I am taking that argument and assign it to a variable. What I need to access is the private method from within colourPalette called "colourClick()", specifically the variable "c" that holds the current color that the user clicked (I tried to return the variable "c" when the function is called so that I can get the value but it doesn't work, I'm missing something. Is there a way to take advantge of that and get the value of that variable "c" and use it in the CircleTool constructor in the "populateOptions" method? I am only allowed to use vanilla Javascript and p5.js methods to create this.

Comment: Does your prof explicitly want you to use ES3 (pre 2015)? Are you allowed to use the "class" syntax?

Comment: The value of "c" is assigned to `selectedColour`, so it should already be available as `colorPalette.selectedColour`.

Comment: It's not really a method, it's just a local function. Local variables and functions are not accessible outside the scope where they're defined. It's not possible to access `colourClick` outside `colourPalette()`. If you want to be able to call it from outside, make it an actual method.

Comment: Thanks guys, I understand that. @CalvinFurano thanks for making me realize, I've just realized I could use it that way, the problem is that the way I am transferring the colourPalette to CircleTool is undefined, not sure why though, do you have any ideas? What I did manage instead was to use the colourP global variable from the main sketch.js file, but I don't understand why it doesn't work for me to pass the colourP as an argument to CircleTool when I create it in the sketch.js file?

Comment: It isn't clear from the code you have provided what the problem you are experiencing is. The code in the question all seems to work fine: https://editor.p5js.org/Kumu-Paul/sketches/eH5sCMOav

Comment: Oh, It looks like the problem is not reproducible because you didn't include any call to `populateOptions` and that is where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is all within your `CircleTool` "class". Within the `populateOptions` function you reference a variable `colorPalette` but no such variable exists in that scope. The `CircleTool` takes an argument, `palette` which would be in scope, so you could just use that. Additionally you assign `this.colorPalette = palette;`, but if you wanted to reference this you would need to use a reference to the `CircleTool` instance. You cannot simply use `this.colorPalette` inside of the callback function passed to the `mouseClicked()` call inside of `populationOptions` because the `this` keyword will be bound to the element being clicked. You could use a local `self` variable, which you would need to assign somewhere in the `CircleTool` function similar to how you in the `ColourPalette` function.

A few other suggestions:

1. beware of using "self" as a variable name, it is shadowing the global `window.self`, which doesn't hurt anything, but it makes it non-obvious when you have forgotten to declare/assign it.
2. avoid using `var`. It should be considered deprecated/harmful, use either `const` or `let` instead.
3. you would do well to follow a more idiomatic class definition style, preferably using the `class` syntax if modern JavaScript is acceptable, or at least declaring your methods on `YourObject.prototype` outside of the constructor function.
4. It is confusing to mix spellings of the word color/colour. Given that p5.js uses the American english spelling color I would suggest you stick with that. However if you want to use colour you should at least be consistent (i.e. why is there a **color**Palette object with a selected**Colour** property‽)

Working version:

```
function CircleTool(palette) {
    this.name = "circleTool";
    this.icon = "/assets/circle.jpg";
    this.colorPalette = palette;

    // Create a self variable to deal with the changing meaning of this in callback functions
    var self = this;
    var startMouseX = -1;
    var startMouseY = -1;
    var drawing = false;
    this.draw = function() {
        //Function to draw the circle
        if(mouseIsPressed) {
            if(startMouseX == -1) {
                drawing = true;
                startMouseX = mouseX;
                startMouseY = mouseY;
                loadPixels();
            }    
            else {
                updatePixels();
                ellipse(startMouseX,startMouseY,dist(startMouseX,startMouseY,mouseX,mouseY));
            }        
        }
        else if(drawing) {
            drawing = false;
            startMouseX = -1;
            startMouseY = -1;
        }
    }
    //adds a button and click handler to the options area. When clicked
    //toggle the fill of the circle
    this.populateOptions = function() {
        select(".options").html(
            "<button id='directionButton'>Fill circle</button>");
        //  //click handler
        select("#directionButton").mouseClicked(function() {
            var button = select("#" + this.elt.id);
            if (self.axis == "fill") {
                self.axis = "notFill";
                console.log(self.colorPalette);
                // set fill based on the colorPalettes current selection
                fill(self.colorPalette.selectedColour);
                button.html('Circle not Filled');
            } else {
                self.axis = "fill";
                self.lineOfSymmetry = width / 2;
                noFill();
                button.html('Circle Filled');
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, this was very helpful, I mixed the color spelling because one bit of code was already given by University and I did not realize that I was using the other spelling of the word but yes, I will keep it consistent. I am at the beginning of Uni so JavaScript is not super friendly to me, however, this is what they were teaching us, I'm guessing the modules are a bit older that is why they make me use the "var" keyword when creating variables and not "const, let" but I'll keep that in mind.  The only thing I did not understand was why was I not able to use the colorPalette without "self"

Comment: Because I did assign the the passed object "palette" to "this.colorPalette" so in theory it should work without using the self keyword? Or maybe it didn't work because I was supposed to write it as "this.colorPalette" inside the populateOptions? But anyway, the issue is resolved, I found a workaround this in the meantime and I am not trying to call the colorpalette from within populateOptions anymore.

Comment: In JavaScript there is no implicit access to properties on `this` so you have to explicitly specify `this.colorPalette` however, you have to be careful where you use `this` because it's meaning changes. In other programming languages like Java `this` refers to the instance of the object where the function is declared, but in JavaScript `this` refers to whatever object was to the left of the `.` when the function was called. So the meaning of `this` can change if you use your function as an event handler or callback. That is why your code makes use of `self`